# Is there away to use ValueError terminal output?

Tags: python, user-interface, valueerror

I was wondering if there is a way to use the terminal output for ValueError when found?
In my case, it works perfectly as is. See attached image. If I could just display it on my GUI, it would instantly improve my UX. I can't imagine having to write codes to capture the error in question '*5'. Does it have something to do with message.py? How do I get there?

[on my wish list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvp8s.png)

[as per Amir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnUpV.png)

Comment: You don't need `if` there, you need `try...except ValueError as e:`

Comment: @Amir, Thanks for responding. I am not too sure what you are asking me to do. See below. It's not what I am looking for. I want the error to show on my GUI as how the terminal spits it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is how you catch and print an exception:

```
try:
    # doing something that raises an error
    a = float('*5')
except ValueError as e:
    error_msg = repr(e)  # this is the error message
    print('Got a ValueError exception!')
    print(error_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign a StringVar (status), bind it to the label (lblStatus), and set the StringVar (status) to the error message from the ValueError.

status = tk.StringVar()

lblStatus = tk.Label(master, textvariable=status)

...

except ValueError as ex:

```
   status.set(str(ex))
```